# Incoming connections are not accepted when on WiFi and LAN connection (Ubuntu)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, lan, services

I run an Ubuntu 16.04 laptop and have several services running (SSH, Apache, etc.). This laptop is connected via WiFi and LAN cable. The WiFi IP address is 192.168.1.100, the LAN IP address is 192.168.2.100. So there are different networks, but I was told that these VLANs are mutually accessible. WiFi is always connected, LAN only when I am at my desk.

I want to allow connections to my laptop from other computers in both networks regardless whether I'm connected via WiFi or LAN cable. That means I should always connect to the WiFi interface (192.168.1.100) from other computers.

When I'm connected via WiFi and LAN cable, my laptop accepts connections only on the LAN interface (192.168.2.100). Nobody can connect to my laptop through WiFi (192.168.1.100). However, when I unplug the LAN cable, my computer is suddenly reachable via WiFi (192.168.1.100) from the same computer. So the VLAN accessibility seems to be true.

Why does my machine accept connections on only a single interface at a time? I'm not aware of applying any specific settings on my machine.

Shouldn't my laptop be reachable via all interfaces that it is connected with?

I can issue requests to both interfaces from my laptop itself, but that does not prove anything, I guess.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I made a further experiment with my laptop in another network where I got 192.168.3.100 (WiFi) and 102.168.3.101 (LAN cable) for my laptop. I could access it from another computer (192.168.3.102) via both addresses without any problems. So it seems to me that my laptop is not mis-configured but it is a network configuration problem.

The netmask is 255.255.255.0 everywhere.

Comment: "mutually accessible" <> "same subnet", so what is the netmask? In any case, even when requests are received on the wlan interface, the answer could be sent through the eth  one, and you "clients" may get very confused by that second machine, so this may be a route problem.

Comment: The netmask is 255.255.255.0 everywhere. I updated the question above.

Comment: So now let's see your routes (output of `route` or `ip route`)  with the three combinations of active interfaces)